# Android Studio Failed to resolve: com.github.Udhayarajan:liquid-swipe-android:1.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-arctic-fox

Having a problem trying to implement Liquid Swipe in Android Studio Arctic Fox

always get Failed to resolve github repo

tried it with the official cuberto liquid swipe repo and with Udhayarajan liquid swipe repo

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(module)

```
   id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
   compileSdk 31

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.tiles"
       minSdk 24
       targetSdk 31
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {

   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'

   implementation 'com.github.Udhayarajan:liquid-swipe-android:1.0.1'
   implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Post the error log also please.

Comment: try with `implementation 'com.cuberto:liquid-swipe:1.0.0'`

Comment: seems like u should add `jcenter()` ( Note - It is deprecated )